# Ember.computed.sort does not properly observe anymore on ember 2.1.0

Tags: sorting, ember.js

I have an `Ember.computed.sort` property in a model, and it used to work fine on ember `2.0.x`. I recently updated to ember `2.1.0` and all of a sudden it stopped working.

The property definition is this:

```
modules: DS.hasMany('module'), 

sortedModules: Ember.computed.sort('modules.@each.position', function (mod1, mod2) { 
    return mod1.get('position') - mod2.get('position') 
}),
```

Now it sorts on application start up, but whenever a `module.position` is changed, it does not re-sort the array: the template is not updated (it should show these modules in correct order), and if I log the `module` objects, I can see that the order is not change.

Any idea?

Comment: I dont think c-properties can re-calculate on async items

Comment: @kristjanreinhold they indeed can. At least on version `2.0.1`